# trouble calling a method in form 2 from a button click on form 1, vb.net

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, methods

I have a program for creating a time sheet and when a saved time sheet is loaded by clicking a button on form 1 the data loads to form 2 and then calls a method in form 2 to print the data to form 3. The problem is after the call `Form2.Print()` there is no data on form 2 if i open it but still works in that the data is printed to form 3. If I remove `Form2.Print()` the data is loaded on form 2 and i can then click the Print button and if i open form 2 again the data is still in the text boxes. NOTE: Ideally I would just send the data to form 2 and form 3 from the Open button click event on form 1 but the `Print()` method on form 2 does many things to the program other than just printing making it easier to just call it instead of replicating it in the Open click. Thank You in advance for the help. Cheers!

Form 1 `Code`

```
    Private Sub Open_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Open.Click
        Dim xmldoc As XmlDocument
        Dim nodelist As XmlNodeList
        Dim node As XmlNode
        Dim objForm2 As Object = Form2 

        xmldoc = New XmlDocument()
        xmldoc.Load("C:\time.xml")
        nodelist = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/Timesheet/Job1")

        For Each node In nodelist
            Dim CustName = node.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText
            Form2.txtbxCustName.Text = CustName
            Dim WO = node.ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText
            Form2.txtbxWONum.Text = WO
        Next

        objForm2.Print()
    End Sub
```

`

Form 2 `Code`

```
    Private Sub btnPrint_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
        Print()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Print()
        Form3.labelCustName.text = txtbxCustName.text
        Form3.labelWOnum.text = txtbxWOnum.text
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Is `Form2` instantiated in `Form1`?  If not you might want to try that.

Comment: instantiated `Form2` and the issue is still there. As a workaround until we figure this out I have found that if I run the load XML code again without the `Print()` call in it I get the desired effect of printing and loading the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to cast `Form2` to object then call print . from new instance of your form you  will directly  call it .And you every time assining new values to text box inside for each block . 
to achieve what you want you can do many ways Instead of `texbox` objects I will show with `String` object.

in your Form2 and Form3 class add

```
   Public Property xmldata as String 'use your own class or other types List  controls(textbox,.)whatever you want . 

    'You have to do inside open click
    Dim form2 as new Form2()
```

If you want initialize form2 and form3 only once and use it accross program then you should add this line to prevent it from **disposing** when `closing()`

```
     Private Sub Form2_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
             Me.Hide()
             e.Cancel = True
     End Sub 


     form2.xmldata=yourxmldata
     form2.print()
     form2.show()'show form2
```

**lemme now if it helped you . if not i will reedit my answer so that u understand**

Comment: Found the answer thanks to you. if i use `Me.Hide` instead of `Me.Close` everything works. thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Create public variable for those 2 labels ..

Add new module to your project and add this into
    public sCustName, sWONum as String

And change your Form2 Print() ..

```
Public Sub Print()
    Form3.labelCustName.text = txtbxCustName.text
    sCustName = txtbxCustName.text
    Form3.labelWOnum.text = txtbxWOnum.text
    sWONum = txtbxWOnum.text
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

So if you need to put back in Form 2 then

```
Form2.txtbxCustName.Text = sCustName
Form2.txtbxWONum.Text = sWONum
```